# Proving that certain subspace of $\ell_1$ is non closed

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, lp-spaces

I need to prove that

$$L= \left\{(x_i) \in\ell_1 : \sum_{i=1}^\infty ix_i= 0\right\}$$ is non-closed in $\ell_1$.

I can't really think of sequences of sequences that are in this subspace, much less one that converges specifically to a sequence not in this space, so help would be appreciated.

Comment: Here is one $x_1=1$, $x_2=-1/2$, $x_n=0$ for all $n\geq 3$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to clarify the hint julien gave in the comments above:

There is a sequence $\{x^{(k)}\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ in $L$, converging in the $\ell_1$ norm to something not in $L$, whose first term is the element $x^{(1)}\in L$ defined by
$$x^{(1)}_1=1,\quad x^{(1)}_2=-\frac{1}{2},\quad x^{(1)}_n=0\text{ for all }n\geq 3.$$

Comment: Not sure I get it. What would the second term be?

Comment: @Brian: Actually, I was thinking of something even simpler:
$$x_1^{(2)}=1,\quad x_2^{(2)}=0,\quad x_3^{(2)}=-\frac{1}{3},\quad x_n^{(2)}=0\text{ for }n\geq 4$$

Comment: Great, Zev's one is simple enough even for me to understand. Thanks.

Comment: Haha glad I could help :) Actually I'm not sure Brian's example works (assuming I've figured out the pattern he's going for) because it is not bounded in the $\ell^1$ norm, and hence certainly not convergent, and our goal is to come up with a convergent sequence in $L$ whose limit is not in $L$.

Comment: You’re right: it doesn’t.

Comment: @user65005: By the way, if my answer is helpful, you can upvote it, and if it's satisfactorily solved your problem, you can accept it, both [as described in the faq](http://math.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask).

Answer (score 1):

[Zev](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/264/zev-chonoles)'s answer solves the problem. We can give a generalization:

> Let $c:=\{c_n\}$ be a sequence of complex numbers. The subspace 
>   $$V_c:=\{x\in\ell^1,\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}c_nx_n=0\}$$
>   is closed in $\ell^1$ (for its natural norm) if and only $c$ is bounded.